# Would trans hydride ligands on a metal complex be beneficial for a catalyst?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

Would trans hydride ligands on a metal complex be beneficial for a catalyst?
Such as alkene metathesis or hydrodefluorination

Answer (score 1):

In alkene metathesis you need large ligands that direct the stereoselectivity of the reaction, and a hydride ligand is very small.

Also for hydrodefluorination I don't see an advantage of a *trans* hydride ligand on the catalyst. *cis* hydride ligands could be beneficial, as they then take the place of the fluorine atom on the substrate.